# Line reflections on the complex plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let $l$ be the line indicated below. [image: here] For certain complex numbers $a$ and $b$, the function $g(z)=a\bar{z} + b$ represents a reflection across $l$. What is the value of $b$?

I've tried converting the line into a Cartesian graph (by taking note of the asymptotes), and I've done so successfully: the graph would be $y = x-2$. However, I'm ultimately unsure of how this could be useful.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3591100/751970 You can check this one for reference

Comment: Is the distance between consecutive grid lines $1$? Also, have you tried plugging in a few comple numbers to see what happens?

Comment: R. Tanuharja, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line seems to be $y=x+2.$ Reflection across this line is 
$$(x_1,y_1) \mapsto (y_1-2,x_1+2)$$ Identifying the point $(x,y)$ with the complex number $x+yi$ gives the equation  $$y_1-2+(x_1+2)i=i(x_1-y_1i)+(-2+2i)$$ Thus $a=i,b=-2+2i$

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the picture you have $g(0)=2-2i$ for example, which yields
$$a\cdot\overline{0}+b=g(0)=2-2i.$$